# Notepad++ remove zeros in decimal places in last two columns

Tags: notepad++

I'm working on a large .csv file, with zeros in the decimal places.

Is there a way to remove the zeros for the **last two columns** only? Heres a snippet of my data:

```
05/02/2002,07:22,0.7405,0.7405,0.7405,0.7405,0,2,2.00,2.00
05/30/2002,06:00,0.7725,0.7725,0.7725,0.7725,1,0,1.00,0.00
06/03/2002,21:08,0.7870,0.7870,0.7870,0.7870,1,0,1.00,0.00
06/04/2002,03:59,0.7875,0.7875,0.7875,0.7875,3,0,3.00,0.00
```

Simply finding and replacing `.00` to "empty" results in some parts of my data in other columns to be condensed into different values.

Comment: Notepad++ might not be the best piece of software for that. See: Microsoft Excel, Openoffice, Libreoffice, etc.

Comment: It's a rather large .csv (close to 2 million entries) that I cannot fully export in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\.00(,|$)` with `$1`

It should be sufficient since no other columns appear to have exactly 2 decimal places. You may need to replace all if you're only matching one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.00(,\d+)\.00$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

DO NOT check `. matches newline`

This will replace `.00` by nothing in the last two columns.

Comment: Would fail on data without two matches in a row e.g. `...,1.00,2.50`

Comment: @Walf: True, but that is not said by OP.

Answer (score -1):

Regex should do the job:
replace "(([^,]*,){8}([^,]*?))(.00)?,([^,]*?)(.00)?"
with "$1,$3"
(without quotes)

worked with input: "05/02/2002,07:22,0.7405,0.7405,0.7405,0.7405,0,2,2.00,2.00"
on http://www.regexe.com/

EDIT: stackoverflow changed the regex when formatting my post. This is the regex i wanted to post: `(([^,]*,){8}([^,]*?))(\.00)?,([^,]*?)(\.00)?`

Comment: With the following excerpt, only 1 occurrence was replaced

Comment: This isn't the correct regex- there should be a `+` after the `[^,]`

Comment: The full correct regex is `(([^,]+,){8}([^,]?))(.00)?,([^,]+?)(.00)?`

Comment: Failed for me. If you're doing it that way, replace `^((?:[^,]*,){8}[^,]+?)(?:\.00)?(,[^,]+?)(?:\.00)?` with `$1$2`